# Invalid XML Architecture when trying to create a view

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am getting a `ValidateError` when trying to install a custom module.

The complete error is the following

```
ERROR openerp3 openerp.tools.convert: Parse error in /openerp/addons/sim/sim_view.xml:39: 
except_osv: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
```

The line is 39 and here is the view

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="buildings_form">
    <field name="name">sim.buildings.form</field>
    <field name="model">sim.buildings</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="building">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="student_name"/>
            <field name="father_name"/>
            <field name="gender"/>
            <field name="contact_no"/>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Do you see something strange with that XML? What else should I be looking at as the possible cause of the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of testing and testing I decided to check my postgres tables to see if my `sim.buildings` table was there and it wasn't.

I could't understand why was that so I started looking at the differences between my non working code and my working code and I noticed that the `_description` tag on my non working code was longer than the average of my working code.

After removing the text in my `_description` it worked.

For anyone else bumping into this question it is also important to restart the server each time you reinstall the module, at least that worked better for me.